# How do I create a text file through python?

Tags: python

I have no idea why this isn't working

```
import time

consumption = "300"
spend = "5000"

def create_report(consumption, spend):

    date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    date = date + ".txt"
    file = open(date, "w")
    file.write("Since: ", pastdate)
    file.write("Consumption in £: ", consumption)
    file.write("Overall spend in £: ", spend)
    file.close()

create_report(consumption, spend)
```

I want to be able to simply create a text file and write in it with the the text file's name as today's date. The "w" doesn't seem to be creating the file. I am getting the error:

```
file = open(date, "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '01/03/2016.txt'
```

Comment: That's not a valid file name on your platform.

Comment: Use something like `date = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")` as an alternative

Comment: try `w+` instead of `w` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Slashes are used to separate directory names; filenames can't contain embedded slashes.  In your example the code is trying to open a file named `2016.txt` in the `01/03` subdirectory, which does not exist.

Comment: Oh I see thanks, yeah it was an issue with the file name

Comment: @JohnGordon For some reason I have been able to create a directory with a slash in its name on Linux. I believe it was a programming error similar to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

consumption = "300"
spend = "5000"

def create_report(consumption, spend):
    # '/' is used for path like `C:/Program Files/bla bla` so you can't use it as a file name
    date = time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
    date = date + ".txt"
    file = open(date, "w")
    # NameError: name 'pastdate' is not defined
    # file.write("Since: ", pastdate)

    # The method `write()` was implemented to take only one string argument. So ',' is replaced by '+'
    file.write("\n Consumption in £: " + consumption)
    file.write("\n Overall spend in £: " + spend)
    file.close()

create_report(consumption, spend)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running this on an operating system where `/` is a directory separator.

Try this code instead:

```
date = time.strftime("%d%m%Y") + '.txt'
with open(date, "w") as f:
    f.write("Since: ", pastdate)
    f.write("Consumption in £: ", consumption)
    f.write("Overall spend in £: ", spend)
```

Note a few things:

- using `with` is much better practice, as it guarantees your file is closed, even if an exception occurs
- it is bad practice to use `file` for your file name